# Should I be mixing .cshtml files and .razor files in my .NET 6 project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, blazor, .net-6.0

I'm not trying to specifically create a Blazor Web application, rather I'm rewriting an old ASP.Net Framework application in Razor and the newest .NET (currently .NET 6). I've created a .razor component for my Footer that is going to appear in all of my pages. I'm unable to get it to display, I currently have this:

```
@section Footer {
    <component type="typeof(NewProject.Pages.Footer)" render-mode="Static"/>
}
```

But then I have read that .razor files are supposed to be used in Blazor Web applications and they should be used *instead* of .cshtml files. I'm trying to stick to Razor pages and MVVM instead of MVC, and I'm still very new to both Razor and Blazor, and before I get too much further into this, I would like to know if I should instead create the Footer as a Partial View instead of a Blazor component. These are the files I've created.

[image: list of files]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Microsoft's answer, apparently, is a big yes.  The default Blazor project uses cshtml as the foundation for the site, as well as for the scaffolded Identity system, and razor for everything else.

I know you're not planning to use Blazor, but the above indicates to me that they're meant to co-exist.

Comment: Great! Now how do I get my Footer component to actually show up on my pages?

Comment: If you're not too far in, I think it would be most expedient to give up your current track and start a Blazor project.  It is the Identity pages in Blazor which use `cshtml`, and since those seem to be the pages you have so far, a little tweaking should allow you to re-use much of your code.